# PHP: View PDF file in my site

Tags: php, pdf

I have a iframe in my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#matwyaafile').attr('src','uploads/<? echo $row['bookfilein']?>');
});
</script>

<iframe id="matwyaafile" src="" width="100%" height="600px"/></iframe>
```

The problem is that when the page is open, Instead of viewing the content of the file in the browser, the file is not showing.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: try to use   $('#matwyaafile').attr('src','uploads/<?php echo $row['bookfilein']?>');

Comment: its same error, i think i need other way to show it

Answer (score 0):

What about escaping those quotes around "bookfilein"?

```
 $('#matwyaafile').attr('src','uploads/<? echo $row[\'bookfilein\']?>');
```